# Netbeans can not save unicode text on JSP file

Tags: jsp, netbeans, unicode, character-encoding, ide

I want to write this Unicode HTML code (Persian) in JSP file in Netbeans 7.4:

```
<b>سلام</b>
```

but on saving file this message shown:

[image: encoding]

I set encoding as UTF-8 in project properties and also done adding:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

to netbeans *etc/netbeans.conf* but nothing changed and after pressing yes button, my Unicode text saved like:

```
<b>????</b>
```

I see that file encoding was UTF-8 but after writing that Unicode HTML and seeing that message its encoding changed to ISO-8859-1!

How can I fix this?

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: @sankrish it is Persian.

Comment: i geuss persian is not listed there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your JSP file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
```

note that Netbeans changes file's encoding according to this code.

Answer (score 1):

If the language you are using is arabic follow this charset `ISO-8859-6, windows-1256, UTF-8`

For more references look [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/b32121/pbr_nls003.htm)

Comment: Your answer says only what charset should I use but in your link I saw how to do it!

Comment: okay :) i thought you would know where to write that code , thats why didnt elaborate it :)